# Parse a file in Linux with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, scripting

I am trying to script out an encryption at rest tool and one part requires me to manually go and get mount point names.

I would like to script something to get these mount point names for me.

EX: mount point location and entry look like this "123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj311" I think is the disk serial number (If there is a way to check this please let me know)

```
cat /etc/fstab

/dev/mapper/123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj311 /ext4 defaults 1 2
/dev/mapper/123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj312 /ext4 defaults 1 2
/dev/mapper/123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj313 /ext4 defaults 1 2
/dev/mapper/123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj314 /ext4 defaults 1 2
/dev/mapper/123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj315 /ext4 defaults 1 2
/dev/mapper/123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj316 /ext4 defaults 1 2
/dev/mapper/123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj317 /ext4 defaults 1 2
```

after its parsed I would like the out put of the file to look just like this so i can then take the file and use it in my script.

```
123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj311,
123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj312,
123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj313,
123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj314,
123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj315,
123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj316,
123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj317
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you thought of doing?  Which commands have you considered? Are you constrained not to use `sed` or `awk` or Perl or Python, or are they options?  It looks pretty straight-forward.

Comment: The only think I been looking at so far is BASH scripting because thats what i know best. But Python is an option and puppet. Im not to familiar with them thou.

Comment: So, how do you write a shell script that reads lines from a file, and splits them into fields that are interesting and those that are not?  How do you find the last component of a pathname (the filename part)?  It is very straight-forward — it could fit in the rest of this answer, but you wouldn't learn much if I spoon-fed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `cut` command for this task, it will easily extract by dividing using delimiters such as space and /. I will give you an working example for you as following;

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1 /etc/fstab|cut -d'/' -f 4
```

This have two sections one will extract the `/dev/mapper/123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj311` and last one will extract the `123412312312nkj12j3j12nj3n21nj311`.

This way you will get what you want from `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: +1: Formally, it doesn't add the commas at the end of all but the last line, but somehow I suspect they probably aren't wanted anyway.